# How do I move elements freely in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: css, visual-studio-2008, styling

The layout menu isnt available as it was in 2005 ..and i tried doing the css-styling modification as was advised in a question asked by someone else.
Doesnt seem to work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh I found a way :) I just set the style manually in the source code i.e set

```vb
style="position:absolute;"
```